# How to train pytorch model using batches with partial information

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

In this PyTorch model I have two streams data with two different modalities that are input into the model at the same time. The streams of data are blocks of sequential data. So I have modality one `M1 = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5]]` and modality two `M2 = [[11,11,11,11],[22,22,22,22],[33,33,33,33],[44,44,44,44]]`. I want to train this model with a system that during training, batches of sequential data will randomly have partial or full information.

So there will be three possibilities during training: `M1` and `M2` will have its full sequential data, or *M1* will be clipped meaning that the sequential data information will be set to zero (e.g. `M1 = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]` ), while `M2` will have its full sequential data info, or `M2` will be clipped meaning that the sequential data information in `M2` will be set to zero, while `M1` will have its full sequential data info.

Are there any PyTorch functions that will do that automatically for me, or does anyone know what would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: Can't you just load both  `M1` and `M2` and with some probability zero out each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `M1` and `M2` be 2D tensors or 3D batched tensors for training, and let `p1`,`p2` and `p3` be the probabilities that M1, M2, or neither is zeroed:

```
p1 = 0.5 # for example
p2 = 0.3 # for example
# p3 = 1- p1 - p2 = 0.2

randn = torch.rand(1)

if randn < p1:
   M1 *= 0
elif randn > p1 and randn < p1+p2:
   M2 *= 0

# pass M1 and M2 to your model
```

As a secondary note, if possible you may want to consider zeroing the gradient for whichever modality had its data erased. You don't really want your network to learn that the zero-values have any significance, which you are at risk of learning.

Depending on the structure of your model, this may be possible. For instance, if `M1` is processed by 1 network branch and `M2` is processed by a different branch, you could constrain so that loss is only back-propagated through the branch that received non-zeroed inputs. For other network structures though, this may not be possible.